# Does $\liminf$ distribute?

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I know the property that for sets $A_n,B_n$
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}(A_n\cup B_n)=\limsup_{n\to\infty}(A_n)\cup \limsup_{n\to\infty}(B_n)
$$
holds.

I'm curious if it also holds that
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}(A_n\cup B_n)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}(A_n)\cup \liminf_{n\to\infty}(B_n)?
$$

Comment: How is the former established?

Comment: No. Consider $A_n$ which is empty for odd $n$ and equal to $\{1\}$ for even $n$, and $B_n$ which is empty for even $n$ and equal to $\{1\}$ for odd $n$. Then $A_n\cup B_n=\{1\}$ for all $n$, so the limit inferior is $\{1\}$; however, each of the limits inferior on the right are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\limsup_{n \to \infty} (A_n \cup B_n)$ contains elements in $A_n \cup B_n$ for infinitely many $n$. These elements are precisely the elements that are either in $A_n$ for infinitely many $n$, or in $B_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

Modifying this argument to $\liminf$ suggests you need to consider intersections instead of unions.

$\liminf_{n \to \infty} (A_n \cap B_n)$ contains elements in $A_n \cap B_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. These elements are precisely the elements that are both in $A_n$ for all but finitely many $n$, and in $B_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} (A_n \cap B_n)
= \liminf_{n \to \infty} (A_n) \cap \liminf_{n \to \infty} (B_n).$$